# AWS S3 access control

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

I need to build an authorization system on AWS. There are some customer records stored in DynamoDB. The customer may have different permission for the S3 resources. So, how can I implement this? I am trying to use API gateway to proxy S3 and use Lambda authorizer to check the record and control the access, is this the right way? Struggling, Struggling...

Comment: very dumb question to ask. I figured out now. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: How did you solve your issue? I am looking into the same

Comment: just as Alex Hague said, use temporary credential. there are 2 functions one is AssumeRole and another is AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity. The second one must work along with Cognito identity pool, but the first one doesn't. You can define the role and the policy to control the permission, and these functions will return tokens, the client can use these tokens to access the AWS service you allowed. You may find more info in the doc. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question really is: **How do I allow my users to access my AWS resources in a secure manner?**

The answer to this is complex and involves many moving parts. The best way to do this is to use Amazon Cognito. There are two flavors of this service, you'll need Cognito Federated Identities and may also want Cognito User Pools:

- **Cognito Federated Identities (Identity Pools)** 
  allows you to take identities from a login provider such as Google / Facebook / etc and provide them with temporary permissions to access your AWS resources such as S3, DynamoDB, API Gateway, etc.
- **Cognito User Pools** 
  is a managed directory for all your users. Cognito Federated Identities can use this as a login provider. You would use this if you wanted to provide an option other than (or as well as) federation with Google / Facebook / etc.

When a user authenticates to your application, **the authentication flow is**:

- The user authenticates to a login provider (e.g. Google / Facebook / Cognito User Pools)
- The user then requests their identity from Cognito Federated Identities
- The user gets credentials for their identity from Cognito Federated Identities
- Cognito Federated Identities makes an AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity call to the AWS Security Token Service. This is where the magic happens, a session is generated from an IAM Role. At this stage any variables in the access policy for the role are resolved. (more on this below)

Your user now has AWS credentials, i.e. an Access Key, Secret Key, and Session Token that can be used to authenticate & authorize calls to AWS services.

A more detailed view of the authentication flow can be found [here in the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html).

**The policy that Cognito Federated Identities assumes can contain variables**. This allows for access policy statements that incorporate the user's Cognito Id. For example, to allow a user to upload a file to their own upload folder in S3:

```
    {
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectTagging"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket/users/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-s3-bucket/users/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Sid": "a1d39796d4604228aa7cf9aa0655555"
    }
```

The important part above is the variable **${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}**. This is replaced with the Cognito Federated Identities user id. So a user is able to upload files to their own folder in your S3 bucket, but not to anyone elses. You can use the same principle to allow downloads, or restrict access to specific keys in DynamoDB.

It's worth calling out that you can also have normal access policy statements that do not involve any restrictions based on user id. These are more useful in situations such as allowing users to invoke APIs via API Gateway.

Amazon have *a lot* of documentation for this, the easiest starting point is [Getting Started with Amazon Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/getting-started/).

Answer (score 0):

why not use [IAM polices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html)? You could limit access to a specific user to a S3 resource easily!
no need for proxies and lambdas...

Create a AWS user with a the following policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:HeadObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:HeadObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/production/some_internal_folder/${aws:username}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

With this policy this user will only be able to access everything at:

**my-bucket/production/some_internal_folder/username/**

Comment: thanks, but I still don't understand. what if I have thousands of customers? I can't create AWS user for each of them.

Comment: aws got you covered there as well (btw you are limited to 5000 users per account) with Temporary Security Credentials(AWS STS API)